# Scrape QS university world ranking (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, xml, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape QS university ranking data by analyzing Ajax interface as the QS global university ranking page is loaded through Ajax. However, I encounter couple of errors when compiling. In this case; I am getting a keyerror type: KeyError: 'url'.

```
url = 'https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/en/3740566.txt?1624879808?v=1625562924528'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 "
                         "Safari/537.36"}
path = 'C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/scrapeQS/qs-rank.txt'


def get_page(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r.json()
    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)


def parser_page(json):
    if json:
        items = json.get('data')
        for i in range(len(items)):
            item = items[i]
            qsrank = {}
            if "=" in item['rank_display']:
                rk_str = str(item['rank_display']).split('=')[-1]
                qsrank['rank_display'] = rk_str
            else:
                qsrank['rank_display'] = item['rank_display']
                qsrank['title'] = item['title']
                qsrank['region'] = item['region']
                qsrank['score'] = item['score']
                qsrank['url'] = item['url']
            yield qsrank


def main():
    json = get_page(url)
    results = parser_page(json)
    for result in results:
        with open(path, 'a') as f:
            f.write(result['rank_display'] + '    ' + result['title'] + '    ' + result['region'] + '    '
                    + result['score'] + '    ' + 'https://www.topuniversities.com' + result['url'] + '\n')
            f.close()
            print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Started parsing！')
    with open(path, 'a') as f:
        f.write('Ranking' + '    ' + 'University' + '    ' + 'Country' + '    ' + 'QS score' + '    ' + 'Link' + '\n')
        f.close()
    main()
    print('Done')
```

Comment: no need for `f.close()` when you do `with open`

Comment: Yes; I will update it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. there is no 'url' in the data.
What make you think there is such key?

Example

```
   {
      "core_id": "624",
      "country": "Italy",
      "city": "Trieste",
      "guide": "",
      "nid": "297237",
      "title": "<div class=\"td-wrap\"><a href=\"\/universities\/university-trieste\" class=\"uni-link\">University of Trieste<\/a><\/div>",
      "logo": "\/sites\/default\/files\/university-of-trieste_624_small.jpg",
      "score": "",
      "rank_display": "651-700",
      "region": "Europe",
      "stars": "",
      "recm": "0--"
    },
```

Comment: Oh; you are right. I am sorry for my mistake. the URL was present on the 2018 ranking data and it isn't anymore in the 2022 one. However; now I am encountering a new error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0101' in position 155: character maps to <undefined>`; Nevermind, I fixed it by using io

Comment: I have one more question please; How can I get title key (w/o html tags) this way: 'University of Trieste' instead of: `<div class=\"td-wrap\"><a href=\"\/universities\/university-trieste\" class=\"uni-link\">University of Trieste<\/a><\/div>`

Comment: use Beautiful Soup in order to extract  the data from the HTML snippet